Authentication from WebSocket interceptor channel not persisted accross the controller and service layers
i am currently working on a spring boot project. i am using spring boot vv3.1.4 and spring security v6.1.4. i have a JWT authentication set up in my project which works fine for HTTP requests. I also have websocket communication in the app. When establishing the websocket handshake i am sending the token as a query parameter and getting it in the JWT service. This approach is also suufficient to authenticate the connection according to the spring Docu. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html#websocket-authentication
My issue is with thee websocket messages, where i try to get the auth from the token again and set it in the context, as the auth is not persisted after the initial auth. I have this preSend channel interceptor:
public class CustomChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

  private final JwtService jwtService;
  private final UserService userService;

  @Override
         public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                    MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                    String authorizationHeader = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization");
                    
                    if (authorizationHeader != null) {
                      if (authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                        String token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
                        String username = jwtService.extractUsername(token);
                        UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                        if(!jwtService.isTokenValid(token, userDetails)) {
                          throw new AccessDeniedException("member");
                        }
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                        accessor.setUser(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                      }
                    }
                return message;
            }
}

i have read about the preSend execution context, as it executed in a different thread, so the SecurityContextProvider resides in another thread in the controller and service layers.
My issue here that i also have a DatabaseAuditing class:
@Component
@EnableMongoAuditing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DatabaseAuditing implements AuditorAware<String> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
      
      if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException());
        return Optional.of(user.getId().toString());
      }

      return null;

    }
}

Some messages will trigger a DB update. the getCurrentAuditor will be then triggered to get the current auditor from the authentication context. The problem is that the context is null when handling a websocket message, and the the context set in the preSend method is not being persisted.
Is there a solution to get the auth object while overriding the getCurrentAuditor method?
